# Where sorting is done in MapReduce Job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop2

Where is sorting done in Hadoop Mapreduce Jobs while we write the program? I am finding difficulty in moving ahead in my program.

Comment: Sorting and shuffling is a part of reducer. What exactly do you want to ask?

Answer (score 2):

The sorting is done by the `Hadoop MapReduce` framework. Mappers output intermediate (key, value) pairs which are passed to reducers. Each reducer gets all keys in sorted order.

**Illustration**:

Say 2 mappers are used:

```
-- mapper1 output
key_a, value_a1
key_b, value_b2
key_c, value_c1
key_d, value_d2

-- mapper2 output
key_a, value_a2
key_b, value_b1
key_d, value_d1
key_d, value_d3
```

Sorting and shuffle (step done by `Hadoop` framework) will ensure intermediate keys are passed to reducers in sorted key order.

Say 2 reducers are used:

```
--- reducer1 input (sorted by keys)
key_a, [value_a1, value_a2]
key_d, [value_d2, value_d1, value_d3]

--- reducer2 input (sorted by keys)
key_b, [value_b2, value_b1]
key_c, [value_c1]
```

If you want to ensure global ordering among keys passed to reducers, you can use a [Total Order Partitioner](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.5/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/partition/TotalOrderPartitioner.html). In this case, each reducer will get input as below:

```
-- reducer1 input (sorted by keys - global)
key_a, [value_a1, value_a2]
key_b, [value_b2, value_b1]

-- reducer2 input (sorted by keys - global)
key_c, [value_c1]
key_d, [value_d2, value_d1, value_d3]
```